# Creating In Memory Object from Linq to Sql Class

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, new-operator

I am using VS 2013 Community Edition and VB Net along with Linq 4.0.  When I execute this command

```
Dim PrimaryContact = New CustomerContact With {
    .Account = BQAcct.Customer_Account,
    .FirstName = BQAcct.First_Name,
    .LastName = BQAcct.Last_Name,
    .Address1 = BQAcct.Address_1,
    .Address2 = BQAcct.Address_2,
    .City = BQAcct.City,
    .State = BQAcct.State,
    .ZipCode = BQAcct.Zip_Code,
    .CellPhone = BQAcct.Cellular_Phone,
    .ContactPhone = BQAcct.Contact_Phone,
    .Email1 = BQAcct.Email_Address}
```

It's as if an InsertOnSubmit command has been issued automatically.  I know this because I execute the GetChangeSet method before and after this command.  After this, a new item is included in the changeset.

All I want is the in-memory object.  I may or may not add the object to the DB later.  If that is not possible, can I remove the object from the cache before I issue the submit command??

Comment: What is `BQAcct`? Could some lazy loading be involved? Just creating a new object can't add it to the change set.

Comment: @Gert Arnold That's what I thought but it does get added.  I will investigate what BQAcct is.

Comment: @Gert Arnold Good instincts!  That was the issue.  The contact links to the Customer in the DB.  Evidently, I should not be adding that object to the newly created object even though there is a place for it.  Thanks for your insight!